# Adding item click event in react native Grid View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please find my code below and help me for adding item click listener for the items in the grid view. Please find the link which I followed [library link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-layout-grid).

And I need to display the name in an alert when the user clicks on each item in the gridlist. Styles are not included in the code

Thanks in Advance

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Platform,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';
import GridLayout from 'react-native-layout-grid';

class HomeScreen extends Component {

renderGridItem = (props) => (
<View style={styles.item}  >
  <View style={styles.flex} />
  <Text style={styles.name} >
    {props.name}
  </Text>
</View>
);
render() {
const items = [];
for (let x = 1; x <= 30; x++) {
  items.push({
    name: `Grid ${x}`
  });
}
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
      Grid Layout
    </Text>
    <View style={styles.flex}>
      <GridLayout
        items={items}
        itemsPerRow={2}
        renderItem={this.renderGridItem}>
      </GridLayout>
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
}


export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `<View>` in your `renderGridItem`, you could use one of the touchables component (react native doc).

For example with `<TouchableOpacity >`:

```
renderGridItem = (props) => (
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => this.showAlert(props.name)}>
    <View style={styles.flex} />
    <Text style={styles.name} >
      {props.name}
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

showAlert = (name) => {
   Alert.alert(
    'Alert Title',
    `The user name is: ${name}`,
    [
      {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap renderGridItem in a TouchableWithoutFeedback?

```
renderGridItem = (props) => (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> Alert.alert(props.name)}>
    <View style={styles.item}  >
     <View style={styles.flex} />
       <Text style={styles.name} >
       {props.name}
       </Text>
     </View>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback />
  );
```

Also you will need to import Alert from react-native.